Выдает ошибку "Поле объекта не обнаружено"
Я хочу реализовать функцию, при которой данные будут автоматически заполняться на основе информации из другого документа.


&НаКлиенте
Процедура Подбор(Команда)

    ПараметрыФормы = Новый Структура("ЗакрыватьПриВыборе, МножественныйВыбор", Ложь, Истина);
    ФормаВыбора=ОткрытьФорму("Документ.УчетПеремещенияОборудования.Форма.ФормаДляСписания", ПараметрыФормы, Элементы.ТабличнаяЧастьСписания);
    
    ПользовательскийОтбор = ФормаВыбора.Список.КомпоновщикНастроек.ПользовательскиеНастройки.Элементы.Найти(ФормаВыбора.Список.КомпоновщикНастроек.Настройки.Отбор.ИдентификаторПользовательскойНастройки);
    ПользовательскийОтбор.Элементы.Очистить();
    ЭлементОтбора = ПользовательскийОтбор.Элементы.Добавить(Тип("ЭлементОтбораКомпоновкиДанных"));          
    
    ЭлементОтбора.ЛевоеЗначение = Новый ПолеКомпоновкиДанных("Ссылка");
    ЭлементОтбора.ВидСравнения  = ВидСравненияКомпоновкиДанных.НеВСписке;
    ЭлементОтбора.Использование = Истина;
    УжеСписали = СписанныеМатериалы();
    ЭлементОтбора.ПравоеЗначение   = УжеСписали;

КонецПроцедуры

Ошибка
Поле объекта не обнаружено (ТабличнаяЧастьСписания)
{Документ.СписаниеОборудования.Форма.ФормаДокумента.Форма(46)}: ФормаВыбора=ОткрытьФорму("Документ.УчетПеремещенияОборудования.Форма.ФормаДляСписания", ПараметрыФормы, Элементы.ТабличнаяЧастьСписания);

Полный код в форме документа
&НаКлиенте
Процедура СписанияОбработкаВыбора(Элемент, ВыбранноеЗначение, СтандартнаяОбработка)
    
    Нафиг = Ложь;
    Для Каждого ВыбранныйЭлемент Из ВыбранноеЗначение Цикл
        
        Для Каждого Строка Из Объект.ТабличнаяЧастьСписания Цикл    
            Если Строка.ДокументОснование = ВыбранныйЭлемент Тогда
                НаФиг = Истина;
                Сообщение = Новый СообщениеПользователю();
                Сообщение.Текст = "Уже добавлено - " + Строка(ВыбранныйЭлемент);
                Сообщение.Сообщить();
            КонецЕсли;
        КонецЦикла;
        
        Если Нафиг=Ложь Тогда       
            НоваяСтрока = Объект.ТабличнаяЧастьСписания.Добавить();
            НоваяСтрока.ДокументОснование = ВыбранныйЭлемент;
        КонецЕсли;
        Нафиг = Ложь;
        
    КонецЦикла;
    
КонецПроцедуры

&НаСервере
Функция СписанныеМатериалы()
    
    Запрос = Новый Запрос;
    
    Запрос.Текст = "ВЫБРАТЬ РАЗЛИЧНЫЕ
    |   СписаниеОборудованияТабличнаяЧастьСписания.ДокументОснование
    |ИЗ
    |   Документ.СписаниеОборудования.ТабличнаяЧастьСписания КАК СписаниеОборудованияТабличнаяЧастьСписания";
    
    Возврат Запрос.Выполнить().Выгрузить().ВыгрузитьКолонку("ДокументОснование");
    
КонецФункции      



&НаКлиенте
Процедура Подбор(Команда)

    ПараметрыФормы = Новый Структура("ЗакрыватьПриВыборе, МножественныйВыбор", Ложь, Истина);
    ФормаВыбора=ОткрытьФорму("Документ.УчетПеремещенияОборудования.Форма.ФормаДляСписания", ПараметрыФормы, Элементы.ТабличнаяЧастьСписания);
    
    ПользовательскийОтбор = ФормаВыбора.Список.КомпоновщикНастроек.ПользовательскиеНастройки.Элементы.Найти(ФормаВыбора.Список.КомпоновщикНастроек.Настройки.Отбор.ИдентификаторПользовательскойНастройки);
    ПользовательскийОтбор.Элементы.Очистить();
    ЭлементОтбора = ПользовательскийОтбор.Элементы.Добавить(Тип("ЭлементОтбораКомпоновкиДанных"));          
    
    ЭлементОтбора.ЛевоеЗначение = Новый ПолеКомпоновкиДанных("Ссылка");
    ЭлементОтбора.ВидСравнения  = ВидСравненияКомпоновкиДанных.НеВСписке;
    ЭлементОтбора.Использование = Истина;
    УжеСписали = СписанныеМатериалы();
    ЭлементОтбора.ПравоеЗначение   = УжеСписали;

КонецПроцедуры



&НаКлиенте
Процедура ПослеЗаписи(ПараметрыЗаписи)
    Оповестить ("ОбновитьПеремещенияТабличнуюЧасть");
КонецПроцедуры

&НаКлиенте
Процедура СписанияПослеУдаления(Элемент)
    Оповестить ("ОбновитьПеремещенияТабличнуюЧасть");
КонецПроцедуры


ФормаВыбора=ОткрытьФорму("Документ.УчетПеремещенияОборудования.Форма.ФормаДляСписания", ПараметрыФормы, Элементы.ТабличнаяЧастьСписания);
Почему Элементы.ТабличнаяЧастьСписания ?
Должно быть прото ТабличнаяЧастьСписания (таб-часть объекта)

Табличная часть - самостоятельная структура, тебе не нужно обращаться к ней через элементы, обращайся просто по имени:
ТабличнаяЧастьСписания

